# Android: How to call budle propeties to text view

Tags: android

Hi i have the following bundle parammeters

```
final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();


        parameters.putString("link", Url);
        parameters.putString("properties", "{"+city+": {\"text\":\"Reply / Recommend\",  \"href\": \""+url+"\"}}");
        parameters.putString("caption", "");
        parameters.putString("name", "");
```

how can i cal these parammeters into a text view, Any suggestions is appreciated

Comment: textView.setText(parameters.getString("link")); But I guess this is not what you need... be more precise please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textView.setText(parameters.getString("link")); is what i need